# do you need to know scala to play around with java play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have come across Java Play Framework and have decided to give it a shot but after digging into the tutorial I have started to see some Scala elements ( index.scala.html ) which has got some Scala related stuff, which I dont understand. I m planning to make a basic chat app with Play in a limited time frame, given the case will I have to learn Scala as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your application in Java without knowing much Scala (except for the views).  When things go wrong, though, you will want to be able to read Scala to debug the framework itself.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need almost at all, Scala is used in the views, however level of required knowledge is similar as you were learning any other templating engine... That's all

Comment: The Scala template engine can also be swapped out for others like Java, Groovy, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you know perfectly @JamesWard, that would be quite expensive transition: native Scala templating engine is faster than Groovy or something, what else it's typesafe which in combination with good IDE ... fasters and secures the development.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the best option but it's not the only option.  :)

Comment: You _will_ get hit with implicit parameters, multiple argument lists, symbols and a bunch of other bit and pieces of scala.  Is that similar to any other template language - maybe, but scala is a _complex_ template language then.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much coding your views will need. If you have complex views, it's a good idea to get somewhat familiar with scala concepts... If your app doesn't have too many views (REST API, for instance) you don't need to touch scala at all.